# Rails Devise SSL Session Mix Up on Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I've deployed my app on to a Ubuntu VPS using Capistrano, nginx/
Passenger and a wildcard SSL certificate.

The app works fine on development and my staging environment on
Heroku.

However, there are two problems on production when users sign into the
site using a secure page.

1. On latest Chrome and Firefox the browsers start to enforce HTTPS
   requests on every single request every time. Regardless if the user is
   signed in or not. Even if I disable SSL on nginx the browser still attempts HTTPS and complains it cannot connect. The main page serves some insecure dynamic embedded
   items and uses an insecure CDN so I would like to serve that page as non-
   SSL. Whenever I tried to redirect a page to non-SSL either through
   nginx rewrite or a before filter in Rails it will cause an infinite
   redirect loop.
2. Safari does not have the first problem as above it respects both
   HTTPS and HTTP requests. However, when the user has logged in and
   browses to a non-SSL page they are signed out or lose the session
   instantly.

Has anyone encountered such a problem before or have an idea on how I could diagnose/fix the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you using Rails 3.1 `force_ssl` to enable SSL, or a gem?

When you enabled HTTPS, you also enabled the the [HTTP Strict Transport Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) flag, which the browse uses to immediately go to any HTTPS page on that domain before it sends the request to the server.

On Chrome, enter `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` into your browser and then you can delete your domain from the HSTS list which should fix it for Chrome. Can't speak for Firefox as I don't use it that often.

The issue with it losing session is likely because Rails is setting the authentication cookie as secure which means they are only sent for HTTPS requests and not HTTP. Make sure your `cookie_options` in Rails are not setting `:secure => true`. Also check the Devise `cookie_options` setting to ensure that `:secure => true` isn't being set.

Comment: You were right about the hsts issue. I'm using Rails 3.1 but I'm not using `force_ssl` rather I am using the gems `gem 'rack-ssl', require: 'rack/ssl'` and `config.middleware.insert_before Rack::Lock, Rack::SSL, :exclude => proc { |env| env['HTTPS'] != 'on' }` in the production config. However, I still can't resolve the login session issue. I've checked the cookie_options and `:secure => true` is not set for either Rails or Devise.

Comment: Looks like Rack::SSL sets cookies to secure by default. How come this affects my app on my server but not on Heroku? Also how might you be able to disable the secure cookies using Rack::SSL?

Comment: I can't speak for Heroku as i don't have experience with it. 

It looks like you can't disable the secure cookie flagging in rack-ssl, one option would be to monkeypatch it to stop `flag_cookies_as_secure` from running.

You could also use the rack-ssl-enforcer gem instead https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer/blob/master/lib/rack/ssl-enforcer.rb#L37 which has an option for enabling secure cookies.